# When I round x in python it returns 0.0

Tags: python, rounding-error

When I try to run `print(round(x, 2))` it shows as 0.0.

Comment: What does `x` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will round to 0 if x is smaller then 0.005.

```
x = 0.005
round(x, 2)
> 0.01

x = 0.0049
round(x, 2)
> 0.00
```

Comment: `round(number[, ndigits])` Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input.
You can find more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#round)